# Read var directly from csv

Tags: variables, powershell, csv, import

Is it possible to read a variable directly by loading a csv?

My csv looks like this:

```
Var,Path

$SrcHost,\\computer
```

Is there a possibility to import-csv and put the path into the var?

Comment: Do you mean having a variable named `var` with "\\computer" assigned?

Comment: No. I would like to be able to use it later in the script using $ScrHost. The $SrcHost should have "\\computer" assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import-csv test3.csv | foreach-object {
iex "$($_.var) = ""$($_.path)"""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `new-variable` (`nv`):

```
import-csv csvfile.csv | % { nv -name ($_.var) -value ($_.path) }
```

However to make this work you have to:

- remove the `$` from the source csv
- *or*, trim `$` as described by the comments below
- *or*, select your variable as `${$srchost}`

Comment: @Simone: Thanks! Ancora più apprezzabile da una connazionale ;-)

Comment: He'll have to change his .csv file for that to work. It's not going to like having the $ already included on the variable name. It will work if you trim it off first. :nv -name ($_.var.trim("$")) -value ($_.path)

Comment: @mjolinor: yes, it would be better the source csv without `$` directly.

Comment: @mjolinor: it will work defintely using `${$srchost}` to access the variable

Comment: I expect it would.  I don't think the OP is expececting to have to use it that way in the rest of his script, tho...

Answer (score 0):

How bout this:

```
Get-Content -Path test.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace(",", "=`"") +
 "`"" } | Invoke-Expression
```